# LINQ Query to solve a complex joining and sorting between two lists to create a new list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Looking for a linq query solve this problem.
Here are two lists : PartOrders and ServiceOrders
there is orderNumber for example 1001X and createdDate on same day for each partOrders and might be many items having same orderNumber so i would sort this list to get only one orderNumber , createdDate and then a list of type .
There is also a another list of type ServiceOrders needs also to be sorted the same way as PartOrders list.
Finally check if the orderNumber match in booth lists(PartOrders and ServiceOrders) and join them in one orderNumber to get new list of Type .

```
public class PartOrders
{
    public string orderNumber{ get; set; }
    public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
    public string orderDescription { get; set; }
    public string OderNote { get; set; }
}
    
public class ServiceOrders
{
    public string orderNumber{ get; set; }
    public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
    public string ServiceDescription { get; set; }
    public string ServiceNote { get; set; }
}
```

So the new list would be with type

```
public class Result
{
    public string orderNumber{ get; set; }
    public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
    public List<TheRestOfOrdersData> theRestOfOrdersData  { get; set; }
    public List<TheRestOfServiceData> theRestOfServiceData{ get; set; }    
}
```

I hope this example helps to understand my question.

```
// PartOrder
List<PartOrders> partOrder = new List<PartOrders>
{
    new PartOrders() { orderNumber = "1001", createdDate = DateTime.Today, orderDescription = "Order spare part", OderNote = "urgent" },
    new PartOrders() { orderNumber = "1002", createdDate = DateTime.Today, orderDescription = "Not Available", OderNote = "Low" },
    new PartOrders() { orderNumber = "1002", createdDate = DateTime.Today, orderDescription = "Available", OderNote = "urgent" },
    new PartOrders() { orderNumber = "1003", createdDate = DateTime.Today, orderDescription = "text", OderNote = "High" },
    new PartOrders() { orderNumber = "1004", createdDate = DateTime.Today, orderDescription = "Order without services", OderNote = "High" },
};

/// ServiceOrders 
List<ServiceOrders> serviceOrders = new List<ServiceOrders>
{
    new ServiceOrders() { orderNumber = "1000", createdDate = DateTime.Today, ServiceDescription = "repair", ServiceNote = "medium" },
    new ServiceOrders() { orderNumber = "1002", createdDate = DateTime.Today, ServiceDescription = "delivery", ServiceNote = "Low" },
    new ServiceOrders() { orderNumber = "1003", createdDate = DateTime.Today, ServiceDescription = "Not Available", ServiceNote = "medium" },
    new ServiceOrders() { orderNumber = "1003", createdDate = DateTime.Today, ServiceDescription = "delivery", ServiceNote = "medium" },
    new ServiceOrders() { orderNumber = "1005", createdDate = DateTime.Today, ServiceDescription = "Service Without Order", ServiceNote = "medium" },
};
```

the list of type List will contain the data :

```
// first item of type Result
{
    orderNumber: "1001",
    createdDate: "Date", 
    List<TheRestOfOrdersData> { orderDescription = "Order spare part", OderNote = "urgent" },
    List<TheRestOfServiceData>{ }
}
// Second
{
orderNumber: "1002",
    createdDate: "Date", 
    List<TheRestOfOrdersData> { orderDescription = "Not Available", OderNote = "Low" },{ orderDescription = " Available", OderNote = "urgent" }
    List<TheRestOfServiceData> { ServiceDescription = "delivery", ServiceNote = "Low" }
}
// and so on
```

Based on the input data you need to groupe

Comment: Are you really sure about the c#-4.0 tag?`

Comment: example input and expected outpout may help understanding this question. 
With 2 or 3 element not a whole set just enought to have one valid result.

Comment: Thanks for your note. No, it should not be.

Comment: Thanks Drag and Drop, i had added an example ,hope this would help

Comment: If there is no order without service and vice versa. You can group then join on `orderNumber`. If you can have service without order but not reciproque a left outer join will be enought. If not enumerate the key of each group and and complete the projection. Can you have order with service , and the other way around ?

Comment: inner join for documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins

Comment: Yes there are some PartOrders with orderNumber that not match any orderNumber in ServiceOrders list and this also apply for ServiceOrders . @DragandDrop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is at least one Order for every service and vice versa.
You can get your information with a simple group and join.

```
// Group order and service on orderNumber;
var groupedOrder = partOrder.GroupBy(x => x.orderNumber);
var groupedService = serviceOrders.GroupBy(x => x.orderNumber);

// Join on the newly created key orderNumber
var joinData = (from o in groupedOrder
    join s in groupedService on o.Key equals s.Key
    select new
    {
        orderNumber = o.Key,
        createdDate = o.First().createdDate,
        orders = o,
        services = s,
    });
```

Demo : https://dotnetfiddle.net/YlWwL3

If there is element in a list and not the other the algo is the following:

1. Group by orderNumber
2. Create each result with the related Order and service

Here I used Lookup instead of groupe cause I know I was going to look for the item of a given orderNumber

```
// Group order and service on orderNumber;
var groupedOrder = partOrder.ToLookup(x => x.orderNumber);
var groupedService = serviceOrders.ToLookup(x => x.orderNumber);

// Get all the key from order , then add the keys from service.
var allIds = new HashSet<string>(groupedOrder.Select(x=> x.Key));
allIds.UnionWith(groupedService.Select(x => x.Key));

List<Result> results = new List<Result> { };
foreach (var id in allIds)
{
    var current = new Result();
    //Is An Order
    if (groupedOrder.Contains(id)) {
        //all order for this Id
        var orders = groupedOrder[id];

        //First item for common information
        var first = orders.First();
        current.orderNumber = first.orderNumber;
        current.createdDate = first.createdDate;

        current.theRestOfOrdersData = orders.ToList();
    }

    //Is An Service
    if (groupedService.Contains(id))
    {
        //all order for this Id
        var services = groupedService[id];

        //First item for common information
        var first = services.First();
        current.orderNumber = first.orderNumber;
        current.createdDate = first.createdDate;

        current.theRestOfServiceData = services.ToList();
    }
    results.Add(current);
}
```

demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PNvFEI

Comment: What a great and professional solution!! I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

```
 var Result = serviceOrders.Select(x => new Result() { createdDate = x.createdDate, orderNumber = x.orderNumber }).ToList();
 Result.AddRange(partOrder.Select(x => new Result() { createdDate = x.createdDate, orderNumber = x.orderNumber }).ToList());
```

This is one possible solution, if u want it, this makes it two steps, but allows u to merge the two list into 1 new big list

Comment: [`Concat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat) ?

Comment: That would not solve the problem of geting a unique orderNumber and created Date and then create a list for the Descriptions and notes related to the order Number